# SSRS Color Expression

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I am trying to change the color of a bar chart column to yellow if it is the current month.  For some reason, SSRS is not recognizing "Today()" or "Now()" as functions.

Basically what I'm trying to say is: `=iif(month(Today()) = Month(Fields!CalendarYearMonth.Value), "Yellow", "#00000000")`.  I keep getting syntax errors under the () after `today`.

CalendarYearMonth is stored as "201308".  I also have a CalendarMonthDesc field (August), or a CalendarMonth field which is (08).

Answer (score 2):

The Visual Studio editor is poor at recognizing proper expressions in the Expressions editor dialog. So I'd ignore the syntax squiggly.

Try this expression, which should force the needed conversion.

```
=iif(month(Today()) = System.Convert.ToInt32(Fields!CalendarMonth.Value), "Yellow", "#000000")
```

It looks like with your current expression you may have problems converting "201308" to the correct date as required by Month().